# Android Lazy Loading With Recyleview or Listview

Tags: android, lazy-loading

I am trying to develop an app option with lazyloading,
at the moment I am loading Json data from the server first and get all image urls in to an array , and then execute lazy loading on listview.

but i want to show images while downloading the json and show it in  the listview 
:(( please help

Comment: please add the code of your adapter so we can tell you what is missing

Comment: But you have to extract the image urls from the json isnt it? When do you want to do that?